# Haml multiline for really long html attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

My coding partner and I spent a lot of time today trying to figure out how to refactor a link with a really long attribute to make it multiline:

```
%a.pull-right{ href: "#", "data-html" => "true", rel: "tooltip", 
  "data-placement" => "left", title: "This is really just so much text. The real thing goes on and on and on, much longer than this. It also contains some line breaks.<br><br>We'd really like to be able to wrap it around so it's readable in the code." }
```

The piping method (`+ |`) listed in the documentation for multiline strings doesn't seem to work in this context. The most readable solution we could come up with is:

```
:ruby
  tooltip_text = %Q(
    This is really just so much text. The real thing goes on and on 
    and on, much longer than this. It also contains some line breaks.
    <br><br>
    We'd really like to be able to wrap it around so it's readable
    in the code.
  )

= link_to '#', class: 'pull-right', rel: 'tooltip', title: tooltip_text,
  'data-html' => 'true', 'data-placement' => 'left' do
```

That's better, obviously, but I'd much rather have it all be in one block. Is there a way to do this without moving the text to another file?

Comment: You could also post that question on code review.stackexchange.com. Maybe it is more on-topic there...

Comment: This may be a good question for Code Review, so long as: **(A)** _the code works_, **and (B)** _it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way_. Please read the [on-topic guide](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting, if you choose to go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If you have any concerns or issues, feel free to [join us at our helpdesk](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34045/cr-help-desk).

Comment: Did you try i18n approach and what is wrong with storing strings in [locales](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-translations)?

Comment: Its http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `|` works okay for me:

```
%a.pull-right{ href: "#", "data-html" => "true", rel: "tooltip",
  "data-placement" => "left", title: "This is really just so much text. |
  The real thing goes on and on and on, much longer than this. It also  |
  contains some line breaks.<br><br>We'd really like to be able to wrap |
   it around so it's readable in the code." }                           |
```

Output:

```
<a class='pull-right' data-html='true' data-placement='left' href='#' rel='tooltip' title="This is really just so much text. The real thing goes on and on and on, much longer than this. It also  contains some line breaks.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;We'd really like to be able to wrap it around so it's readable in the code."></a>
```

Note that even the last line needs to have the pipe character at the end of it.

Also, you might need to change the `<br>`s to `\n` to get new lines to work properly in the browser.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. I can't figure out what we were doing wrong yesterday, because it's working exactly like it should today.

Comment: Key for me here was seeing that the line with the closing } had the | as well!